# Having issues in passing a variable to another page in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, parameter-passing, hidden-variables

```
<?php
$hostname = "****";   //name of the server
$username = "***";   //id of the user
$password = "****"; //password of the user
$db = "**";          //name of the database

//connect to the database
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if (!$conn) {
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

//select the database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ("Can\"t use " . $db . mysql_error());
}
echo "<form action='Assign6next.php' method=\"post\">";
$sql= "SELECT * FROM Author"; //This selects all columns from author

echo "Author List"; //Echo name
echo "<br>";
$result= mysql_query($sql, $conn);        //The result of the query in database
echo '<select name="AuthorName"><OPTION>';//Creates dropdown for Author dropdown
echo "Select an Author</OPTION>";         //
echo "<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ //While in the loop return results in row
$last= $row["AuthorLast"];                 //Create variable last for Last Names
$first = $row["AuthorFirst"];              //Create variables for first Names
echo "<OPTION value=$last,$first>$last,$first</OPTION>"; 
} 
echo '</SELECT>';                             //End of drop down list
echo "<br>";

echo "<INPUT type='submit' value='Get Titles' name='submit'>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
//echo "button 1 has been pressed"; 
$auth = $_POST['AuthorName'];
//echo $auth;
//echo "<br>";
//$data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
list($lastn, $firstn) = explode(",", $auth);
echo "<input type='hidden' name='lname' value=$lastn>";
//echo "</INPUT>";
//echo '<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="'.$lastn.'">';
//echo '<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="' . htmlspecialchars($lastn) . '">';
//$_COOKIE['lname'] = $lastn;

//echo $lastn; 
//echo "<br>";// foo
//echo $firstn; // *
} 

echo "</form>";

///////
//close the connection to MySQL
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

here in the above code I have lastname string in $lastn and passing this as hidden variable to another page.

```
<?php
$lastn = $_POST['lname'];
echo $lastn;
echo "string";
?>
```

I'm trying to catch the hidden variable using above code but only "string" is getting displayed but not the last name which i'm getting from previous page.

Comment: Not entirely sure but try using quotes for it, such as `value='$lastn'>`

Comment: Are you inside a `<form>` with this?

Comment: Is that part of a form?

Comment: I tried using value='$lastn' but it didn't work
Yes the first page is inside a form.

Comment: Also, there is no tag <\input>. It's self closing like <input \>

Comment: @JAL there are no such tags neither in HTML nor in XHTML, for HTML it is just `<input>` for XHTML `<input />`

Comment: The question is lacking for more information where did `$_POST['AuthorName']` came from, invalid html tag and doesn't need to tag session and cookies when OP cite post values only

Comment: I edited the question so that every thing can be seen.

Comment: @CharanVoma form (and it's hidden value) is posted to Assign6next.php, is it first or second file?

Comment: @llyaBursov Assign6next.php is the second file

Comment: @CharanVoma then, you have logical problem - you're drawing form without lname field, then it posted to next file, so your condition to create new field newer executed

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to persist the value across page loads without having to resubmit a form, you will need to use sessions, like so:

page1.php

```
session_start();
$lastn = 'something';
$_SESSION['lastn'] = $lastn;
```

page2.php

```
$lastn = $_SESSION['lastn'];
```

Cheers

Comment: Plus session_start() before any of that

Answer (score 0):

This is no valid HTML. Try:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="'.htmlspecialchars($lastn).'">';
```

And don't forget the form around the fields.

Comment: still the same result. I placed everything in a form.

Comment: You can test if the POST isset when you make a var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST). Test it on the new site if the POST is set and you values are set in it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your first page to:

```
$auth = $_POST['AuthorName'];
list($lastn, $firstn) = explode(",", $auth);
echo '<form method="post" action="nextpage.php">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="lname" value="' . htmlspecialchars($lastn) . '">';
echo '<input type="submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

then open this page in browser and you will see form with button, after pressing button data will be posted to nextpage.php (rename it) and you will see value